# jQuery - Check if element is a parent

Tags: jquery

I know with filtering it is

```
$("div:parent")
```

but how do I see if the element is a parent using traversing?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean by "using traversing". Do you just want to test if [childNodes](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/childNodes) isn't empty ?

Comment: sorry, the question is confusing. can you show some codes and rephrase the ques?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to jQuery. By traversing I mean this: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/
Yes, basically I want to see which "div" does not have any childNodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('div:has(*)')
```

or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('div').has('*')
```

If you want to check if it has any contents.. use the [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector

```
$('div:empty')
```

Comment: be careful with `:empty` selector, white space in element causes it to fail   http://jsfiddle.net/HGmEG/

Comment: to workout the white space for the empty, check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're not happy with `$('div:parent')`, and want to explicitly call a jQuery traversing method, you might use

```
$('div').filter(function(){return $(this).children().length})
```

If needed, we might propose even slower or less readable.

Note that this isn't exactly the same that using childNodes. If you want to see if there is no content, including text, you might prefer

```
$('div').filter(function(){return $(this).contents().length})
```

Comment: I think you want to use `$(this).children().length`

Comment: `return $(this).contents().length == 0`? I think OP wants empty divs, not not-empty divs.

Comment: @SalmanA I don't think so : " how do I see if the element is a parent"

Comment: I don't know, he mentioned _Yes, basically I want to see which "div" does not have any childNodes_

Comment: This question and comments are... puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is **:empty** http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

but be careful, if there are whitespace inside empty doesnt consider them as empty.
so you could make another selector/expression

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/7WdmD/

```
$(function() {
    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
    empty_noWhiteSpace: function(a,i,m){
        return $.trim(a.innerHTML) === '';
    }
});

    $('ul li:empty_noWhiteSpace').addClass('is_empty');
});?
```

because when you have a list item like this

```
    </li>
    <li>
    not empty
    </li>
```

that first li item has newline, so it is still considered not **':empty'** tag